# Using permuted list to populate two-dimensional array with special order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-itertools

I want to create a 2D array containing tuples or lists which requires a particular order.

Using `itertools.product` I am capable of creating the required permutations:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

elements = 2
n = 3

temp = []
for tuples in itertools.product(np.arange(elements,-1,-1), repeat=n):
    if sum(tuples) == elements:
        temp.append(tuples)

print temp
```

This will print:

```
Out[1277]:
array([[2,0,0],
       [1,1,0],
       [1,0,1],
       [0,2,0],
       [0,1,1],
       [0,0,2]])
```

The array should then be created to yield:

```
array = [[(2,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,2,0)],
         [(1,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,0)],
         [(0,0,2),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)]]
```

and is subsequently used to compute a dot product:

```
array2 = [1,5,10]

np.dot(array, array2)

Out[1278]:
array([2,6,10,11,15,0,20,0,0])
```

However, `itertools` does not yield the order I am looking for. 
Therefore, I am using `argsort` and basically 1D arrays in the end:

```
array = itertools.product(np.arange(elements,-1,-1), repeat=n)

sortedArray = array[array[:,1].argsort()]

print sortedArray

Out[1279]:
array([[2,0,0],
       [1,0,1],
       [0,0,2],
       [1,1,0],
       [0,1,1],
       [0,2,0]])

result = np.dot(sortedList, array2)
```

This works fine in combination with `np.pad` to restore the original size (3x3 = 9):

```
np.pad(result, (0, array.size - result.size), "constant")

Out[1280]:
array([2,6,10,11,15,20,0,0,0])
```

However, the order is not retained.

The reason for doing this, is a second reference array that uses the same structure as the array above, which can be raveled:

```
reference = [[foo,bar,baz],
             [bar,bar,0],
             [foo, 0, 0]]

np.ravel(reference)

Out[1281]:
array([foo,bar,baz,bar,bar,0,foo,0,0])
```

I am looking for a solution that does not need the work-around.

Comment: And why are you sorting only based on the second column?

Comment: @yatu The reason being the underlying mapping of the arrays. Array2 is sorted by increasing values, so that the dot product always yields a certain combination of the elements in array2.

Comment: @Fourier On my side, the first line `print list(itertools.product(np.arange(elements,-1,-1), repeat=n)`, once the `()` fixed into `print (list(itertools.product(np.arange(elements,-1,-1), repeat=n)))` doesn't return what you show.

Comment: @Mathieu Sorry, I forgot some of my code. Fixed and thank you